# FreeRADIUS2 and LDAP Authentication

Tags: centos, openldap, freeradius, freeradius2

I am currently running a CentOS 5.5 box with FreeRADIUS2 on it. I have the simple authentication turned on right now (username and pass is set via /etc/raddb/users). I want to have FreeRADIUS authenticate users via my current OpenLDAP server. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might try http://vuksan.com/linux/dot1x/802-1x-LDAP.html#OpenLDAP_security

I've set up authentication against Active Directory using FreeRadius2 but obviously there are enough differences between OpenLDAP and AD to use instructions specific to your ldap setup.

OpenLDAP should be easier than AD to get up and running though.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this question. In my research I found that CentOS keeps the ldap configuration file in /etc/raddb/modules/ldap.

In my setup I am using PEAP so my LDAP server stores LM hashes. A short mention of how to set this up is here: http://vuksan.com/linux/dot1x/802-1x-LDAP.html#PEAP_with_OpenLDAP

Once I found the ldap config file and read through everything in that file, setup was fairly simple. The only tough part that I ran into was having to use the sambaLMPassword but that was easily over come with a little googling.

Edit: This link: [Setting up RADIUS + LDAP for WPA2 on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/47815/setting-up-radius-ldap-for-wpa2-on-ubuntu) also helped out a ton on getting everything working.

Comment: Thanks for the second link! It really helped me get LDAP to work with FreeRADIUS atleast in terms of it verifing users. Now the second issue I am having with with only allowing a certain group named "RADIUS" on my LDAP be verified.